# Poor scrolling performance UICollectionView with UIImage swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, horizontal-scrolling

I know similar has been asked before and I spent most of the evening implementing answers mentioned by others but I still have laggy scrolling and would appreciate if you can look at my code.

I have a simple `UICollectionView` with 5 `UIIMages`, I have small amount of lag when I scroll. Here is my code

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
       cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
            let design: Design = self.currentDesigns[indexPath.item] as! Desig
                        let Imagepath = design.coverImages[0] as? String
                        let images = UIImage(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(Imagepath, ofType: nil)!)
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            cell.imageView.image = images
                            cell.imageView.frame = cell.bounds
                            cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
                        }}
      return cell
}
```

I also used `UIIMage(named:` to cache the image but still have the scrolling issue.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the UICollectionView scroll smoothly if you take out the image loading code?  How about if you take out setting the frame and clipsToBounds properties?  Narrowing down what's causing the poor performance might give a clue as to the problem.  Also, how big are the images?  If they're gigantic and you're resizing them on the main thread, that could be the issue.  You should probably ensure that the images are all already appropriately sized for display if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Scrolling works fine without the image loading. I narrowed down the issue and it is happening when the UImages are assigned to cell. I resized the images as they are stored locally and each image is now roughly 50kb JPEG file.

Comment: Have you tried running with Instruments to find any hotspots in your code?

Comment: @Abizern haven't done that yet but pretty sure the UIImage is causing the issue as I have nothing else going on in the code

Comment: I'm also suspicious of hitting the disk everytime you dequeue a cell?

Comment: @Abizern that might be a clue. Any idea what should do if that's the case

Comment: Hmm.  Abizern's instruments suggestion is good.  Some other things you could check: Is it making more cells than you think it is?  Throw a print statement in the code where you apply the image and make sure it's only getting called 5 times for 5 images.  You could also try working around setting the frame; if you already have properly-sized images, you shouldn't have to do that.  Also, perhaps try using a different GCD priority, like DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW and see if it changes the responsiveness.

Comment: @mosn Are you seeing any flashing of your images as you scroll?

Comment: @abizern No just lagging. Very small millisecond lagging.

Comment: Last time I faced an issue with this (a large shopping app with lots of images) we wrote our own image cache to fix the issue. The image was resized to the exact size that we needed for display.

Comment: @Abizern guess I have to do the same. Maybe caching is the solution here. Thanks a lot for your time :). I'll update if this resolved the issue

Comment: If your minimum target is iOS 8, then you can try moving all the code that sets the image into "
- collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:"

Comment: Also, if there are only 5 images total, then you shouldn't load them from disk every time. Just save them into an array or a dictionary in your view controller.